# Drop near identical rows based on value difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello I have a pandas dataframe (around 1000 rows) that can be summarize like that:

```
     Date      Distance
0   2014-08-13   5.9
1   2014-08-17   10.7
2   2014-08-13   6.2
3   2014-08-20   13.7
4   2014-08-13   8.8
5   2014-08-17   10.9
```

I would like to drop rows when the Date is identical and the distance difference between the two rows are less than 0.5. 
My data is not ordered

In this micro case the result I'm looking for is getting this dataframe back:

```
     Date      Distance
0   2014-08-13   5.9
1   2014-08-17   10.7
3   2014-08-20   13.7
4   2014-08-13   8.8
```

index 2 has been dropped because it's the same date as index 0 and the difference between the two distance was less than 0.5 .

index 5 has been dropped it's the same date as index 1 and the difference between the two distance was less than 0.5

I'm kind of clueless of how to tackle this problem efficiently. Thanks for your help !

**Edit** : I wasn't clear enough with my previous example. it's not compared to the first distance (or the smallest) of a particular date. it's between any two distance of particular date.

This example is maybe more explicit :

```
     Date      Distance
0   2014-08-13   5.9
1   2014-08-17   10.7
2   2014-08-13   6.2
3   2014-08-20   13.7
4   2014-08-13   8.8
5   2014-08-17   10.9
6   2014-08-13   3.3
7   2014-08-13   3.6
8   2014-08-13   3.5
9   2014-08-13   1.7
```

it should return :

```
     Date      Distance
0   2014-08-13   5.9
1   2014-08-17   10.7
3   2014-08-20   13.7
4   2014-08-13   8.8
6   2014-08-13   3.3
9   2014-08-13   1.7
```

Comment: for quick response you should provide what you try, it's not do my work forum

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to check for two conditions to either keep a row or not:

- The difference with respect to the first in each group is greater than `0.5`
- The row is *not* the first in a group

---

For that you could define both conditions and chain them with a `bitwise OR`:

```
m1 = df.Distance.sub(df.groupby('Date').Distance.transform('first')).abs().gt(.5)
m2 = ~df.Date.duplicated()

df[m1|m2]

         Date  Distance
0  2014-08-13       5.9
1  2014-08-17      10.7
3  2014-08-20      13.7
4  2014-08-13       8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simple thing:

- GroupBy on `Date` column. This will cater to duplicate dates.
- Take `diff` of all rows within a group.
- Pick rows where `diff` is `Nan` or greater than `0.5`

**Commands:**

```
In [43]: df['diff'] = df.groupby('Date')['Distance'].diff()
In [47]: df[(df['diff'].isna()) | df['diff'].ge(0.5)].drop('diff', 1)
Out[47]: 
         Date  Distance
0  2014-08-13       5.9
1  2014-08-17      10.7
3  2014-08-20      13.7
4  2014-08-13       8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my way using this approach but it seems a bit messy

```
df = df.sort_values(['Date','Distance'])
df['Date_s'] = df['Date'].shift(+1)
df['Distance_s'] = df['Distance'].shift(+1)

def remove_near_duplicate(distance,distance_s,date,date_s):
    if (date == date_s) & (abs(distance-distance_s)<0.5):
        return False
    else:
        return True

df['To_drop'] = df.apply(lambda row : remove_near_duplicate(row['Distance'],row['Distance_s'],row['Date'],row['Date_s']),axis=1)

df = df[df['To_drop']==True]
df.drop(columns=['To_drop','Date_s','Distance_s'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Did you consider any of the proposed approaches?

Comment: yes both works on the small example but no the extended one

Comment: Well perhaps you should consider clarifying the question then, since they do seem to answer the question in this post.